# Angular 6 & Material keep service state through dialog

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I have 2 forms. Each of these forms have it's own material dialog to grow up with it's current state.

So, PersonComponent is used by RequestComponent and ResponseComponent but with two differents states of the PersonService.

The problem is that, currently, the state can be the same for each components if it's provided at CoreModule's level. It could be different for each if it's provided at PersonComponent's level.

I tried also to provided at RequestComponent & ResponseComponent's level but it seem to be wrong.

Here is a reproduction of it on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/poc-grow-form?embed=1

Comment: Are you talking about Form Is valid state?

Comment: I try to save the form state between multiples components

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used Material's data for Dialogs (MAT_DIALOG_DATA) to give the right instance of my service.

```
this.dialog.open(PersonDialogComponent, { 
  data: { service: this.personService } 
});
```

Then give it to personComponent through input

```
<app-person [service]="data.service" ></app-person>
```

And finally check if the personComponent need the input or not

```
@Input("service") inputService: PersonService;
personService: PersonService;

constructor(private _personService: PersonService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.personService = this.inputService ? this.inputService : this._personService;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/poc-grow-form?embed=1&file=src/app/core/person/person.component.ts